# 500 error when trying to set up an .htaccess redirect

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I couldn't find a solution to my problem anywhere. Nothing seemed to fit.

I'm trying to add this code to my .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteBase /
RewriteEngine On

# Check if mobile=1 is set and set cookie 'mobile' equal to 1
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)mobile=1(&|$)
RewriteRule ^ - [CO=mobile:1:%{HTTP_HOST}]

# Check if mobile=0 is set and set cookie 'mobile' equal to 0
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)mobile=0(&|$)
RewriteRule ^ - [CO=mobile:0:%{HTTP_HOST}]

# cookie can't be set and read in the same request so check
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)mobile=0(&|$)
RewriteRule ^ - [S=1]

# Check if this looks like a mobile device
RewriteCond %{HTTP:x-wap-profile} !^$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "android|blackberry|ipad|iphone|ipod|iemobile|opera mobile|palmos|webos|googlebot-mobile" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Profile}       !^$

# Check if we're not already on the mobile site
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}          !^m\.
# Check to make sure we haven't set the cookie before
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Cookie}        !\mobile=0(;|$)
# Now redirect to the mobile site
RewriteRule ^ http://mobile.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

Every time I add it to my .htaccess, I get the 500 error.

Here's what's in my .htaccess now:

```
# -FrontPage-
IndexIgnore .htaccess */.??* *~ *# */HEADER* */README* */_vti*

<Limit GET POST>
  order deny,allow
  deny from all
  allow from all
</Limit>
<Limit PUT DELETE>
  order deny,allow
  deny from all
</Limit>
AuthName example.com
AuthUserFile /path/to/file/service.pwd
AuthGroupFile /path/to/file/service.grp
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /blog/
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule . /blog/index.php [L]
</IfModule>


# do not index specified file types
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
  <FilesMatch "\.(doc|docx|xls|xlsx|pdf|ppt|pptx|xml|mp3)$">
    Header set X-Robots-Tag "noindex"
  </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>

Redirect 301 "/blog/2010/03/05/the-power-of-the-radio-jingle/"http://example.com
Redirect 301 "/blog/2010/02/10/how-to-write-for-voice-over/"http://example.com
```

What am I doing wrong? I've never edited a .htaccess before. Please help!

Thanks!

Comment: Just so you're aware having a mobile site isn't good for Google rankings. You should have a responsive website instead.

Comment: Try adding space between `Redirect 301` links, and try to remove `"` from arount `/blog/2010/...` redirect link. Also your first code part is missing closing tag for `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>`

Comment: Please add the segments one after one and see, which one introduces the 50 error. Also try to find an error log.

Comment: The .htaccess stuff I posted works but might not be exactly as appears in the files, as I had to add the 4 spaces to every line to make it appear as code.

Comment: I don't appear to have access to an error log with the host we use. I don't even have a cPanel I can look at. It's only when I add the new stuff for the redirect that the error occurs.